# Brew upgrade python returns "python not installed"

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to upgrade from "Python 3.7.3" to "Python 3.8" with `$ brew upgrade python`. But when I try, brew returns:

```
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 2 formulae.

Error: python not installed
```

I know python is installed because I've been using it for months. I can confirm this by running, `which python3`

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

And `python3 --version`,

```
Python 3.7.3
```

I don't know what is causing this?

Could the issue be that `python --version` still points to python2, `Python 2.7.16`.

---

### UPDATE

I also confirm I've run `brew cleanup` and `brew doctor`.

`brew info python` returns

```
python@3.8: stable 3.8.5 (bottled)
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/python@3.8.rb
License: Python-2.0
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
Required: gdbm ✔, openssl@1.1 ✔, readline ✔, sqlite ✔, xz ✔
==> Caveats
Python has been installed as
  /usr/local/bin/python3

Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
  /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/libexec/bin

You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages

See: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python
==> Analytics
install: 587,815 (30 days), 1,615,984 (90 days), 2,710,078 (365 days)
install-on-request: 187,760 (30 days), 307,168 (90 days), 343,355 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

Comment: `python not installed` means Python wasn't installed **by homebrew**.

Comment: What does ``brew info python`` have to say?

Comment: @khelwood This is a reasonably new mac machine, and I think I've only used homebrew. I guess it's possible I accidently installed without it...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I've added what `brew info python`  returns above. TBH, it's beyond my comprehension.

Comment: The important part is the ``Not installed`` line. Please install it before trying to upgrade it.

Answer (score 9):

The solution was to install python with brew.

```
brew install python
```

I assumed it had already been installed, but that was the system (not brew) version.

The error, `Error: python not installed` implied that python had not been installed with brew.

Answer (score -1):

In https://discuss.python.org/t/updating-python-under-usr-bin-python3/13020
python developer recommends avoid touching the system Python **(/usr/bin/pythonX)**, and install your own copy (via Python.org , Homebrew, Anaconda, etc).